# INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

When submitting a form I was testing the amount of information I can send via HTTP. I am using Mysql DBMS. I have an application that runs several Texarea field. Example a form with 10 texarea (I use a field limiter to validate the amount of typed character). For each Texarea I allow, the user can enter up to 400 characters. The question is, is there any way for Mysql to accept more values? Is there any configuration, what should be done? Example Every Texarea Accept 2000 Character! The information generated in the console follows: INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this listener follow below:

1. `<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>`
   on your server.xml, remove it and try. You can not use a keystore if you are using the APR connector.
2. Also try by setting maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576" attribute on the Connector node in server.xml

Comment: I followed her recommendations and the error generated was:
Java.sql.SQLException: Got error 139 from storage engine

Deeper into the subject, the Mysql limits in 8000 bytes, which compromises the application. I had to limit each texarea with 600 (texarea fields in the application to the total 12 x 600 = 7200), there are also other fields like date, name, etc. Is there any way to change in Mysql's limitation?